# Dell XPS 13 Hangs up if attach an external Monitor

Tags: unity, xorg, dell, xps

I have an Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook with Ubuntu 12.04. its works pretty well, but if I attach my Apple Cinema Display with the Mini Display Port then hangs the Notebook up.

Its totally randomly. Power attached or not, freshly restarted or not, monday or friday.  I cant see any pattern for the problem.

The X Log says nothing. Only the last line looks very suspicious:

```
[    35.539] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    35.539] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.01  1366 1414 1446 1498  768  769 773 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz)
[    35.539] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   47.34  1366 1414 1446 1498  768 769 773 790 +hsync -vsync (31.6 kHz)
[    85.997] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "CMN", prod id 4920
[    85.998] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    85.998] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   71.01  1366 1414 1446 1498  768 769 773 790 +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz)
[    85.998] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   47.34  1366 1414 1446 1498  768 769 773 790 +hsync -vsync (31.6 kHz)
[    86.469] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1920x1968 stride 7680, tiled
[    86.592] BUG: triggered 'if (!dev->valuator || dev->valuator->numAxes < 2)'
BUG: ../../dix/getevents.c:850 in scale_to_desktop()
[    86.592] 
Backtrace:
[    86.593] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x26) [0x7f3f3e231866]
[    86.593] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7f3f3e0a9000+0x621fe) [0x7f3f3e10b1fe]
[    86.594] 2: /u%
```

Comment: Have you installed the drivers for your graphics card?

Comment: It runs out of the Box. No Drive needed. Do you have any Suggestion?

Comment: I don't know of your graphics hardware, if you have nvidia or ati, it's better to install those drivers. The generic drivers struggle with hardware acceleration and multiple monitors. I have a nvidia chip and I use `nvidia-settings` to configure my multiple monitors when required.

Answer (score 2):

The “xorg-server” version  2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.4 should fix it, but the new version 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.6 don't have this fix.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/921236